# PHP preg_replace: remove punctuation from beginning and end of string

Tags: php, regex

What regular expression can I use in PHP to remove all punctuation from the beginning and end of a string?

Comment: It's helpful to also post your attempt.

Comment: I'm new to RegEx, so I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regex, probably something like...

```
$str = trim($str, '"\'');
```

Where the second argument is what you define as *punctuation*.

Assuming what you *really meant* was to *strip out stuff which isn't letters, digits, etc*, I'd go with...

```
$str = preg_replace('/^\PL+|\PL\z/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Even better, didn't think of that.

Comment: trim with the 2nd argument is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Might depend on your definition of punctuation.  If it's "anything but alphanumerics" or something like that, then a regular expression may be the way to go.  But if it's "period, question mark, and exclamation point" or some other manageable list, this will be easier to understand:

```
trim($string, '?!.');
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you call punctuation, but:

```
preg_replace('/^\W*(.+?)\W*$/', '$1', $source);
```

Comment: That's an interesting regex... you sure that is going to work?

Comment: @alex: No. Fixed now :) But `trim` is much better anyway.

Comment: I still think it's off a bit, you probably want to put those chars inside of a character class, e.g. `[;.]`.

Comment: So long as you don't expect any chars outside of the ASCII range :P

Answer (score 0):

To keep only alphanumeric chars

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '', $string);
```

for ALL ponctuations:

```
preg_replace('[:punct:]+', '', $string);
```